# Trying to pass a string in a ViewController to a string in a NSObject.. but it dosn't work

Tags: nsstring, uitextfield, viewcontroller, nsobject

Hi Im trying to pass a NSString thats in a ViewController over to a NSString in an NSObject.
Here is the code that I am using in my NSObject to call the string and pass it to my new string.

```
    RegisterDeviceViewController *S = [[RegisterDeviceViewController alloc] init];
tempRegCode = S.checkString;
NSLog(@"tempRegCode=%@",tempRegCode);
```

the problem being once the button it pressed on the view that starts the method in my NSObject it works sweet however nothing gets passed to tempRegCode.. here is my Log.

> [Session started at 2011-05-03 09:27:35 +1200.]
>   2011-05-03 09:27:36.264 instaCode1.3[1456:207] yum yum feed me more cookie!! func=ERROR
>   Code=1
>   Text=Please Register Device
>   2011-05-03 09:27:36.266 instaCode1.3[1456:207] cookieCode = code1
>   2011-05-03 09:27:37.983 instaCode1.3[1456:207] alerts.m OK button pressed
>   2011-05-03 09:27:49.539 instaCode1.3[1456:207] Users Registration is '22222-22222-22222-22222'
>   2011-05-03 09:27:49.540 instaCode1.3[1456:207] tempRegCode=(null)

As you can see at the end there 'tempRegCode=(null)??

And this is how I passed the variable to checkString

```
- (IBAction)submitRegistration:(id)sender{
//NSLog(@"submit Registration button has been pressed");

//add text format here
checkString = regTextField.text;
NSLog(@"Users Registration is '%@'",checkString);

regConnection *Reg= [[regConnection alloc] init];
[Reg startRegConnect];
```

}

Comment: I think we need to see more code. What does the registerdeviceviewcontrollers init method look like?

Comment: Surly if the UItextField is being passed to an NSString (as showing from the NSLog) inside the view controller I should be able to pass that string over to a NSObject. When you say you would like to see the init method are you referring to the method where I accept input into my text field?

Answer (score 0):

In order to access checkString like that, you need checkString to be a nonatomic property.

At the bottom of your RegisterDeviceViewController.h, just before `@end`, add

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *checkString;
```

Then, at the top of RegisterDeviceViewController.m, just after `@implementation RegisterDeviceViewController`, add

```
@synthesize checkString;
```